# Redirect from no number to any number

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a blog and I try to remove the numbers from the url. So I use RewriteRule in the .htaccess to redirect

For instance.

From blog/first-post
To blog/1-first-post

I write in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/first-post/?$ /blog/1-first-post [R=301]
```

It works well, but I have to write a rule for each post. 
My question is: Is it possible to have a RewriteRule that works for all the posts? I mean:

From:
blog/first-post
blog/second-post
blog/third-post

To:
blog/1-first-post
blog/2-second-post
blog/3-third-post

I tried and it does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(\D*)/?$ blog/\d{1,3}-$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: The number that is being used in replacement is not coming from original URL so how do you think you can use `Any-Number`?

Comment: what's he's asking is this:  where does Any-Number come from!?? you're just using a hard coded '1'

Comment: The number is just the number of the post. 1 is the first post, the second is 2-second-post ...

Comment: I updated my question to clarify

Comment: Where is the rewrite rule meant to magic this number from?

Comment: @cmbuckley. Do you mean that it is not possible to have a generic in the replacement? something like \d ?

Comment: @segon Not in this flavor of a regex.

Comment: @segon presumably there is a specific ID for `first-post`. You're saying that you want that ID to end up in the destination URL, but you give no indication where that ID comes from. It's the responsibility of the `RewriteRule` to produce the specific destination URL.

Comment: Look into `RewriteMap`